# Is there any Jquery plugin that will restrict a HTML file uploader only to accept images

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

I saw a lot of file up loader plugins .I dont want to use the  entire file upload plugin ..

Means , I am using my own code. But i didnt find a way to restrict the file type the uploader accepts .. How can i do that? . Is there any plugin which doing only this function ( I don't want to use a full file uploader plugin)

Comment: You can use a validator to only accept the extensions you want.

Answer (score 4):

This requires HTML5, jQuery is not needed. I think it will be small enough to use pure JavaScript:

- first you can set the [accept attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/Input#Attributes) to `image/*`
- after that you can use the [File Api](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-slicing-files) to read the first bytes for the [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Examples) - [image numbers demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPoFN.png)

These are just some ideas. You can devise some heuristic to check the file type based on this.

Comment: A concrete example of the use of the html "accept attribute" would have been useful for newbies like myself. Here's one i found: `<input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">`