# FileUpload: Show alert when file type is an image

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload

A simple file upload

```
<dl>
    <dt><label for="fileupload">{L_FILENAME}:</label></dt>
    <dd>
        <input type="file" name="fileupload" id="fileupload" maxlength="{FILESIZE}" 
               value="" />
    </dd>
</dl>
```

I need a check for images `(jpg, jpeg, gif, png)`. When there is an image, an alert message should say: `"You are trying to upload an image. Please use the image uploader"`.

**Note**: The image-check should start directly after the file is selected and not after the form is submitted.

Is this possible with jQuery?

I tried many solutions without success. Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231058/file-type-validation-with-javascript

Comment: if you add accept="image/*" in input type ,then you dont need such alert.It automatically suggests you only images.

Comment: @Banik please read my question. I dont want only images. I want everything without images ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am correct then you are looking for  `.change` event.

```
$("#fileupload").change(function (e) {});
```

Now use the below code,

```
$("#fileupload").change(function(e) {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val.match(/(?:gif|jpg|png|bmp)$/)) {
        alert("You are trying to upload an image. Please use the image uploader!");
    }
});
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/2r64r57j/)

Possibly, you could play with the Regex to match your file extensions `/(?:gif|jpg|JPG|JPEG|png|PNG|bmp)$/`.

[<kbd>Updated Fiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/vdkL8g75/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: yes, thats what I mean. Perfect. I have only a lil suggestion. Is it possible to add a lowercase option, that JPG will also work? Maybe you can edit your answer? thank you very much.

Comment: You should be able to do it [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/vdkL8g75/). Just play with the regex `gif|jpg|JPG|JPEG|png|PNG|bmp`

Comment: @Shubh, Thanks for perfect answer.