# Django: file field validation in model using python-magic

Tags: django, django-models, django-file-upload, python-magic

I have a model containing file field. I want to restrict it to pdf files. I have written clean method in model because I want to check for admin and shell level model creation also. But it is not working in model clean method. However form clean method is working.

```
class mymodel(models.Model):
    myfile = models.FileField()

    def clean():
        mime = magic.from_buffer(self.myfile.read(), mime=True)
        print mime
        if not mime == 'application/pdf':
            raise ValidationError('File must be a PDF document')

class myform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = mymodel
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean_myfile(self):
        file = self.cleaned_data.get('myfile')
        mime = magic.from_buffer(file.read(), mime=True)
        print mime
        if not mime == 'application/pdf':
            raise forms.ValidationError('File must be a PDF document')
        else:
            return file
```

If I upload pdf, mime in form clean method is correctly validating (printing 'application/pdf'). But model clean method is not validating. It is printing mime as 'application/x-empty'. Where am I doing wrong ?

Also one more problem is that if model clean method raise validation error, it is not shown as field error in form, but it is showing as non-field errors. Why so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using form validation you are not to be worry about model clean method

You are already doing correct thing in form

```
def clean_file(self):
        yourfile = self.cleaned_data.get("your_filename_on_template", False)
        filetype = magic.from_buffer(yourfile.read())
        if not "application/pdf" in filetype:
            raise ValidationError("File is not PDF.")
        return yourfile
```

If you want to use model clean you can make your own validator

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27916582/5518973

You are using server side python-django validation but javascript is also nice way for validating file client side.For javascript regex validation you can look out for this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17067242/5518973

or if you are able to use plugins you can use jquery validation plugin

https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: Unfortunately, the above code won't work. `filetype` will be something like `'PDF document, version 1.3'`. You'll need the assignment to be `filetype = magic.from_buffer(yourfile.read(), mime=True)` in order to get `"application/pdf"`

Comment: This only worked when I did 
if str(filetype) != "application/csv":
            raise ValidationError("File is not a CSV file.")

Answer (score 0):

```
fields = '__all__'
```

A suggestion from Two Scoops of Django: Best Practices for Django 1.8

> 26.14 Don't Use ModelForms.Meta.fields = "__ all __" - This includes every model field in your model form. It’s a shortcut, and a dangerous one.
>   It’s very similar to what we describe in section 26.13 (Don't Use ModelForms.Meta.exclude) and even with
>   custom validation code, exposes projects to form-based Mass Assignment
>   Vulnerabilities. We advocate avoiding this technique as much as
>   possible, as we feel that it’s simply impossible to catch all
>   variations of input.